# JavaScript in Visual Studio - Closure style comments

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, comments, google-closure-compiler, xml-comments

Does anyone know of any projects that support using Closure-style comments in Visual Studio?

Microsoft has their XML comments, but as far as I know their Ajax Minifier does not use them for type information to optimize code. Ideally, it would be nice to be able to get smart completion when writing Closure comments, and to have them parsed to give Intellisense when mousing over functions and variables.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you know this already but I just found this:
http://jasongoemaat.blogspot.ca/2011/07/intellisense-for-google-closure-library.html
If you are already using Google Closure, adding the above file will add intellisense in VS.

Also, MS has released TypeScript which integrates nicely within VS itself, though the jury is still out on that one if it is as reliable as Closure.

Comment: This seems to be about helping Visual Studio autocomplete function and method names in the Closure library. More interesting would be to make it understand type annotations in code for the Closure Compiler, or automatically transform code between TypeScript and JavaScript with Closure annotations (without changing the code other than adding annotations/type info).